# Is it possible to call an api exposed internally through Azure API M from another aks cluster?

Tags: api, azure-aks, azure-api-management

The api is deployed in one cluster and is exposed internally through Azure API M. The requirement is to call this API from another cluster, when tried, there is an error 404. Is it possible to get this done?

Comment: Maybe if they are part of the same virtual network or, if there is some sort of dns resolution that translate the request from cluster a to cluster b?

Answer (score 0):

If both the APIM and AKS are hosted in the same subscription, then it is possible to call an API exposed internally through APIM from the AKS cluster

Under Network in your API Management Service, add your AKS virtual network with a new subnet

Now, your API in the APIM can be called from your AKS cluster

If the APIM and AKS are hosted in different subscriptions, you need to peer both the virtual networks (AKS VNET and APIM VNET)

Then, you would be able to call the API from your AKS cluster

**Reference**:[Control ingress to AKS with Azure API Management (pumpingco.de)](https://pumpingco.de/blog/control-ingress-to-aks-with-azure-api-management/)

Comment: Is it possible to call an API which is deployed in cluster a from cluster b?

Comment: if both the clusters virtual networks are peered, you would be to call the API